# Möbius Inversion Forumla for for $\sum_{n}\pi(\sqrt[n]{x})$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion

Consider a function $$J(x)=\sum_{n}\frac{\pi(\sqrt[n]{x})}{n}$$ with the prime counting function $\pi(x)$. This sum is finite, because for $n$ big enough $\sqrt[n]{x}<2$ and therefore $\pi(\sqrt[n]{x})=0$. The author of a book then applies the möbius inversion formula to get
$$\pi(x)=\sum_n\mu(n)\frac{J(\sqrt[n]{x})}{n}$$
However, I am only aware of the inversion formula in for cases like
$$g(x)=\sum_{d\mid x}f(d)$$ or $$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^x f\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)$$
Also I was unable to adapt the known proofs for the other results due to technical reasons. Especially because of the upper bound of summation (the first $n$ with $\sqrt[n]{x}<2$) makes it hard to juggle with sums embedded into each other and makes it impossible (for me) to copy the quite easy proofs of the other cases.

I would appreciate any help on this problem how to prove the wanted version of the inversion formula

Comment: There is an answer below which gives the detail of your computation. However, if you're interested, Mobius inversion is a very general procedure and may be applied to any partially ordered set. You can see Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics (https://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/putnam/enu_comb_stanley.pdf) for an explanation of Mobius inversion in full generality. Briefly, the Mobius inversion formula is a simple statement about an algebra acting on a vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\ge1}\mu(n){J(\sqrt[n]x)\over n}
&=\sum_{n\ge1}{\mu(n)\over n}\sum_{m\ge1}{\pi(\sqrt[mn]x)\over m}
=\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{m\ge1}\mu(n){\pi(\sqrt[mn]x)\over mn} \\
&=\sum_{k\ge1}{\pi(\sqrt[k]x)\over k}\sum_{mn=k}\mu(n)=\pi(x),
\end{aligned}

where the last equality follows from the fact that

$$
\sum_{mn=k}\mu(n)=\sum_{d|k}\mu(d)=\begin{cases}
1 & k=1, \\
0 & k>1.
\end{cases}
$$